does anyone know who Gubinsky is in the Gubinsky-Melts variation of the Scandinavian Defence
The Gubinsky-Melts variation of the Scandinavian defence is named after correspondence master Michael Melts and Gubinsky, however I can't seem to find out who this Gubinsky is. the opening starts 1. e4 d5 2. exd5 qxd5 3. nc3 qd6
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "?"]
[Round "?"]
[White "?"]
[Black "?"]
[Result "?"]
[Title "Gubinsky-Melts"]
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "1"]

1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Qxd5 3. Nc3 Qd6


I'm not familiar with Gubinsky or Melts, but are you sure Gubinsky is a "who", instead of maybe a "where"? Wikipedia indicates that there are towns in Russia with the name: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gubinsky

There's a book written by Melts, I'm trying to get a copy of it, but it's proving to be a pain, When I finally find it; I'll circle back to this question.

There is a book available from Second Story Books via Amazon that seems to be it: https://www.amazon.com/Scandinavian-Defense-Dynamic-3-Qd6/dp/1888690550/ref=sr_1_1?crid=K9PYT3N7D11I&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.utajiIwSR4cFnt7NtbpA4z4_xLsruw2tVoz9TLHwY90.CdPzmPeOxTsWZLOKHyGT6LVxmPY1svObA30dPZSjClc&dib_tag=se&keywords=scandinavian+chess+melts&qid=1714480157&s=books&sprefix=scandinavian+chess+melts%2Cstripbooks%2C95&sr=1-1
